# Using an or statement in template

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the template I'm trying to evaluate:

```
<div class='block'>
              <h4> Info </h4> 
              <input type="text" value='<?= exampleId || "" ?>' id="example-id">
              <br>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type='text' id='name' value='<?= name || "" ?>'>
          </div>
```

I run:

`HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()`

This line of code crashes with a reference error explained below.

In my template, I am trying to use an OR statement, ex:

`<?= exampleId || "" ?>`

I am getting an error saying reference error `exampleId` is not found.

Wouldn't `exampleId` evaluate to "undefined"?

Ex:

```
var someObj = {};
somObj.exampleId  // ===> undefined

someObj.examplId || 'hello world' // ===> 'hello world'
```

Why doesn't the template evaluate the expression?

Comment: Are you trying to search the HTML content for a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from documentation:

> Inside a scriptlet, you can write any code that would work in a normal Apps Script file:

If this code is run in the code editor:

```
function test() {  
  return exampleId || "";
}

function runThis() {
  Logger.log(test())
}
```

It produces an error.

The only way that:

```
<?= exampleId || "" ?>
```

will work, is if `exampleId` is declared as a global variable.

```
var exampleId;//Declared outside of any function block
```

Going back to the example, even if there is an test for undefined:

```
if (exampleId===undefined) {return ""};
```

There is still an error in the code editor.

So, it won't run in the code editor.

I wanted to test whether it would run in the browser:

```
<script>
  exampleId || "";
</script>
```

That produces and error in the console.

Comment: Hey Sandy, thanks for the input! When I run this in the chrome console: `exampleId || ""`, it returns the empty string.  The template from my understanding will look on itself for any properties assigned to it.